# PHP giving 8.8817841970013E-016 instead of 0

Tags: php, floating-point

I am doing a simple calculation in PHP.

`(2.70 + 2.30 + 29.70 + -2.30 + -29.70 + -2.70)` - got these figures from a database

PHP is giving `8.8817841970013E-016` as answer instead of zero.

I have tried functions like round, number_format but still get the same results

Comment: well it has to be displayed on a report, is there no means for PHP to do the calculation exactly?

Comment: You might want to read up on floating point numbers.  Long story short, there's some numbers you just can't represent in binary, just like you can't represent 1/3 in decimal.  As for a fix, number_format() would probably do nicely, unless the calculation is critical.  In that case you're better off avoiding floating point.

Comment: what was the result of your attempts to use round or number_format<

Comment: This is a duplicate of pretty much every question tagged `floating-point` on this site. There is a whole website devoted to answering this question: http://floating-point-gui.de

Answer (score 2):

Floating point arithmetic can create inaccurracies with some numbers.

If you want to do arithmetic like this that doesn't have these errors (is it currency?), try doing them as integers and divide by 100 in the end:

```
php > echo (270 + 230 + 2970 + -230 + -2970 + -270)/100;
0
```

If it is in fact currency, store them as `DECIMAL` in the database and let the database do the math.

Also, `round` should work fine:

```
php > echo 2.70 + 2.30 + 29.70 + -2.30 + -29.70 + -2.70;
6.2172489379009E-15
php > echo round(2.70 + 2.30 + 29.70 + -2.30 + -29.70 + -2.70);
0
```

I also found [a page with more info](http://floating-point-gui.de/) on it, from the PHP documentation site.

Comment: Always, when the numeber is not representable as binary number.
e.g. 1/4 may be expresed without any error. but 1/10 is periodic and some rounding must be done during division.

Comment: That is completely untrue. Floating point arithmetic operates under different rules than real number arithmetic, but that doesn't mean that the differences are errors.

Comment: This is not completely wrong, i dont understand these fast downvotes.

Comment: I downvoted because of the first sentence: "Floating point arithmetic always has errors." This is a common misconception, and it is completely untrue. Floating-point arithmetic is completely accurate (more accurate than decimal math, in terms of absolute error in ulps) -- it is only the conversion to and from base-10 string representations that is inexact. Of course, if the values you are measuring are discrete, not continuous (e.g. currency), you need a representation that preserves the discrete granularity. But that doesn't mean floating point is flawed for other uses.

Comment: @DanielPryden I updated the first sentence. I'd appreciate if you would have pointed it out, instead of downvoting. Then I could've edited it (and learn something along the way!)

Comment: @BartFriederichs: I've removed my downvote. I did leave a comment explaining why I had downvoted, although my first comment was admittedly rather terse. Sorry for my slow typing, I'm on a tablet at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

The decimal representation of your expression is "0.00000000000000088817841970013". That is a value very close to 0 and is there because of the standard problems when calculation with floating point numbers on computers.

If you want to dig deep into why this is so there is a great article available at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html (but beware, its quite deep :) )

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
round(2.70 + 2.30 + 29.70 - 2.30 - 29.70 - 2.70)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the appearance of the numbers in the question, this may be a case in which exact handling of decimal fractions with two digits after the decimal point is important. If so, consider working in units of hundredths. For example, US currency can be treated as an integer number of cents, rather than a two decimal place dollar quantity.

You can still use the normal number parsing, but as soon as you get the number multiply by 100 and round to nearest integer. Similarly, on output divide by 100 and format to two decimal places. Do the intermediate calculations on the integer values.

I recommend reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)